# Is "among a tray of X" grammatical?

Tags: grammar

Is among a tray of something grammatical? I am not sure but using among before a singular word seems ungrammatical, but I am not sure, because it's a tray of a bunch of things.

I found this particular excerpt, but I am not sure how grammatical it is. Many of the results from Google use archaic language or just straight out incorrect language.

> ...a main document selector designed to select a desired document from
>   **among a tray** of encoded documents transported thereto...

Another example:

> A toy was hidden among a tray of other toys

Comment: Could you add more detail to explain what you think a "tray of documents" represents?  It doesn't sound like the right noun to use in this situation, but I don't know what to suggest as an alternative.   It's certainly *grammatical*, just not *idiomatic*.

Comment: Well, I too have no idea what was meant by it since it came from a patent document. How would you reword the second sentence if it's not idiomatic?

Comment: I couldn't say until I understand the context better.   You can have a *file* of documents, or a *box* of documents, or a *sheaf* of documents, or *binder* of documents, or lots of other possibilities. It's kind of a poorly written sentence -- I mean obviously a "document selector" is something that "selects a document" so why repeat the obvious?   But I know in some industries a software company is paid by the amount of documentation they generate, not by the quality of the software they produce, so verbosity is encouraged.  I'm not kidding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Among** needs a group of things, and you can describe a group by the container it's in: *a tray of encoded documents*, or *a box of chocolates*, or *a whole jar of spiders*. So this is OK.

*Tray* sounds odd, because you don't normally keep documents (or toys) on a tray, but maybe it makes sense in context.

Comment: Documents are put in a tray, as a simple filing system. There are the terms "in-tray" and "out-tray".  Though they are no used as often (in a computerised office), these used to be physical trays, and they contained documents.